# How to import/export all build-hints from one project to the other?

Tags: codenameone

I have a Code Name One Projet that has a lot of **Build-Hints**.
I created a new project that needs to use the same build hints.
Adding manually all hints in the new project takes a long time and is very error-prone.
Is it possible to export the hints from one project to the other,
or in the opposite way, to import the hints from one project to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy all the entries starting with `codename1.arg` from the previous `codenameone_settings.properties`.